# removeEventListener not working on window object

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events, click

I can't get my removeEventListener to work. I am passing in what I believe is exactly the same function, so I am not sure why it isn't working. I think it may have to do with the fact that I am using it on the window object.

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", changeColor, true);

function changeColor() {
    const sectionToChange = document.querySelector("section:has(#color-select)");
    const colorSelector = document.querySelector("#color-select");
    colorSelector.addEventListener("input", event => {
        sectionToChange.style.cssText += `background-color: ${colorSelector.value}`;
    });
}

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", removeEvents);

function removeEvents() {
    const removeListenersButton = document.querySelector("#remove-listeners");
    removeListenersButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
        console.log("clicked");
        window.removeEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", changeColor, true);
    });
};
```

Everything works fine except removing the event listener. The "clicked" prints out to the console as well.

Comment: What effect do you expect the `removeEventListener()` to have in this case? The `DOMContentLoaded` event is usually (or always?) fired once per page load regardless.

Comment: @ivar I am essentially trying to stop the background color from changing after there has been a "click" event. So really I would like to negate that second EventListener in the changeColor function

Comment: Then you need to remove the event listener you are passing to the `colorSelector.addEventListener("input", ...)`, not the `DOMContentLoaded` event listener. Currently you pass that arrow function directly so you don't have a handle to pass it to a `removeEventListener()`. You'll have to store that function somewhere where the `removeEventListener()` can access it and that pass that stored function to the `colorSelector` input event.

Comment: Ah ok that makes sense. I will try that, thanks! And after reading a little more about DOMContentLoaded I'm pretty sure your first comment is accurate - it fires once and removing it has no impact.